# How to convert between uint64_t and poly64_t on ARM?

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, arm64, neon

I'd like to perform polynomial multiplication of two `uint64_t` values (where the least significant bit (the one got by `w&1`) is the least significant coefficient (the a<sub>0</sub> in for w(x)=∑<sub>i</sub>a<sub>i</sub>*x<sup>i</sup> )) on ARM and get the least significant 64 coefficients (a<sub>0</sub>...a<sub>63</sub>) of the result as `uint64_t` (so `result>>i&1` is a<sub>i</sub>).
It's not clear to me, however, what is the standard-compliant way to convert `uint64_t` to `poly64_t` and (least significant part of) `poly128_t` to `uint64_t`.

> poly8_t, poly16_t, poly64_t and poly128_t are defined as unsigned integer types. It is unspecified whether these are the same type as uint8_t, uint16_t, uint64_t and uint128_t for overloading and mangling purposes.

> ACLE does not define whether int64x1_t is the same type as int64_t, or whether uint64x1_t is the same type as uint64_t, or whether poly64x1_t is the same as poly64_t for example for C++ overloading purposes.

source: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101028/0009/Advanced-SIMD--Neon--intrinsics

Above quotes opens some scary possibilities in my head like perhaps the bit order is flipped, or there's some padding, or who knows, maybe these are some `struct`s.

So far I've come out with these two:

```
poly64_t uint64_t_to_poly64_t(uint64_t x) {
  return vget_lane_p64(vcreate_p64(x), 0);
}
uint64_t less_sinificant_half_of_poly128_t_to_uint64_t(poly128_t big) {
  return vgetq_lane_u64(vreinterpretq_u64_p128(big), 0);
}
```

But they seem cumbersome (as they go through some intermediary stuff like `poly64x1_t`), and still make some assumptions (like that `poly128_t` can be treated as a vector of two `uint64_t`, and that the the 0-th `uint64_t` will contain the "less significant coefficients", and that least significant polynomial coefficient will be at the least significant `uint64_t`'s bit).

OTOH it seems that I can simply "ignore" the whole issue, and just pretend that integers are polynomials as the two functions produce the same assembly:

```
__attribute__((target("+crypto")))
uint64_t polynomial_mul_low(uint64_t v,uint64_t w) {
    const poly128_t big = vmull_p64(uint64_t_to_poly64_t(v),
                                    uint64_t_to_poly64_t(w));
    return less_sinificant_half_of_poly128_t_to_uint64_t(big);
}

__attribute__((target("+crypto")))
uint64_t polynomial_mul_low_naive(uint64_t v,uint64_t w) {
    return vmull_p64(v,w);
}
```

that is:

```
        fmov    d0, x0
        fmov    d1, x1
        pmull   v0.1q, v0.1d, v1.1d
        fmov    x0, d0
        ret
```

also, the assembly for `uint64_t_to_poly_64_t` and `less_sinificant_half_of_poly128_t_to_uint64_t` seems to be a no-op, which supports the hypothesis that there are no steps involved in conversion, really.
(See above in action: https://godbolt.org/z/o6bYsn4E4)

Also:

```
__attribute__((target("+crypto")))
uint64_t polynomial_mul_low_naive(uint64_t v,uint64_t w) {
    return (uint64_t)vmull_p64(poly64_t{v},poly64_t{w});
}
```

seems to compile, and while the `{..}`s give me the soothing confidence that no narrowing occurred, I'm still unsure if the order of the bits and order of the coefficients are guaranteed to be consistent, and thus have some worries about the final `(uint64_t)` cast.

I want my code to be correct w.r.t. to standards, as opposed to just work by an accident, as it has to be written once and run on many ARM64 platforms, hence my question:

**How does one perform a proper conversion between polyXXX_t and uintXXX_t, and how does one extract "lower half of coefficients" from polyXXX_t?**

Answer (score 1):

The ARM-NEON intrinsic set provides many types, but fundamentally they just map to the same set of registers. The types are there to help you, the programmer, organize your code and the hardware really doesn't care.

Many implementations of ARM-NEON intrinsics just set all those types to some internal variable, so the type-safety is largely lost in those cases: Visual C++ and clang/LLVM are both fairly "loose" with respect to ARM-NEON type-safety.

GNUC seems to be one compiler that I've used that generates these type warnings, although you can you use `-flax-vector-conversions`.

The ARM-NEON intrinsic set defines a number of `vreinterpret_X_Y` and `vreinterpretq_X_Y` instructions. These are for doing the 'type-casts' between the various types when you need to force them for the particular mix of instructions you are using.

```
// Convert poly to unsigned int (the reverse is also defined)
vreinterpret_u8_p8
vreinterpret_u8_p16
vreinterpret_u16_p8
vreinterpret_u16_p16
vreinterpret_u32_p8
vreinterpret_u32_p16
vreinterpret_u64_p8
vreinterpret_u64_p16

vreinterpretq_u8_p8
vreinterpretq_u8_p16
vreinterpretq_u16_p8
vreinterpretq_u16_p16
vreinterpretq_u32_p8
vreinterpretq_u32_p16
vreinterpretq_u64_p8
vreinterpretq_u64_p16
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is not to use the `poly128_t` or `poly64_t` types at all, as this leads to very bad code generation mixing neon and GPR registers.

```
poly128_t mul_lo_p64(poly128_t a, poly128_t b) {
    return vmull_p64(a, b);
}
        fmov    d0, x0
        fmov    d1, x2
        pmull   v0.1q, v0.1d, v1.1d
        mov     x1, v0.d[1]
        fmov    x0, d0
        ret
```

This is seen also in more complex scenarios.

To fix this, one should stay completely in the neon register domain and needs just two primitives, namely

```
inline poly64x2_t mul_lo_p64(poly64x2_t a, poly64x2_t b) {
    poly64x2_t res;
    asm("pmull   %0.1q, %1.1d, %2.1d": "=w"(res): "w"(a), "w"(b));
    return res;
}
inline poly64x2_t mul_hi_p64(poly64x2_t a, poly64x2_t b) {
    poly64x2_t res;
    asm("pmull2   %0.1q, %1.2d, %2.2d": "=w"(res): "w"(a), "w"(b));
    return res;
}
```

Then e.g. the two other often used intrinsics `poly64x2_t vaddq_p64(poly64x2_t a, poly64x2_t b);` and `vextq_p64(poly64x2_t,poly64x2_t,1);` work as expected.